# Load table based on json data

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to figure out how to display back to a user a table based on a json file. I know how to print the basic table using javascript by doing

```
      var myVar = setInterval(function(){ 
        $.getJSON(
          $SCRIPT_ROOT + '/load/',
          {},
          function(data){
            $.each(data['result'], function(i, item){
              console.log(data['result'][i].data.value);
              var clone = $('#template').clone(true).attr('id','');
              clone.find('.name').html(data['result'][i].name);
              clone.find('.spread').html(data['result'][i].data.thing);
              clone.appendTo('table');
            });
        });
      },500);
```

However when you wrap this function with `setInterval()` tag so that it loads the json file ever `500ms` it will just continually append the the results on to the end. How can i just update the table with the values that have changed?

Comment: Well what you're seeing is what `.appendTo()` is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to renew table content, just remove table content before $.each loop

```
  var myVar = setInterval(function(){ 
    $.getJSON(
      $SCRIPT_ROOT + '/load/',
      {},
      function(data){
        $('table').empty()
        $.each(data['result'], function(i, item){
          console.log(data['result'][i].data.value);
          var clone = $('#template').clone(true).attr('id','');
          clone.find('.name').html(data['result'][i].name);
          clone.find('.spread').html(data['result'][i].data.thing);
          clone.appendTo('table');
        });
    });
  },500);
```